# Missing records from Mule ConsumerIterator

Tags: java, collections, mule

I am using a Mule component to process records from a Salesforce query. I wrote a Mule component to use the ConsumerIterator to aggregate the records in batches of 100. However, I don't get all the records. I included a simple count to count all the records and I am using an AtomicInteger to count the total values handed off to the method handOff. I also print out the thread name, as I don't believe it is a threading issue. I am using a synchronous flow. I am using a quartz component but I had configured it to use only 1 receiver thread. This should ensure that I am using the same thread for processing. I have included the code. The Thread name is the same throughout. The ConsumerIterator reports 7348 records and the 'count' variable also reports 7348. However the AtomicInteger counter reports 7276 records, i.e. 72 records short.
Please could someone look at this an tell me why and how to fix it?

```
 public class Aggregator implements Callable {

   private Logger LOG=LoggerFactory.getLogger(Aggregator.class);

    private AtomicInteger at=new AtomicInteger();

  public Aggregator() {
  }

   @Override
   public Object onCall(MuleEventContext context) throws Exception {
    Object obj=context.getMessage().getPayload();
    ConsumerIterator<HashMap<String,Object>> iterator=
               (ConsumerIterator<HashMap<String,Object>>)obj;
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> l=new ArrayList<>();
    LOG.info("Iterator has "+iterator.size()+" elements!");
    int count=0;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
    count+=1;
        Object payload=iterator.next();
        LOG.info("Processing Next:: => "+payload);
        if(l.size()<100){
            l.add((HashMap<String,Object>)payload);
        }else {

             LOG.info("Just handing off to write :: => Size is "+l.size());
             handoff(l);
             l=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        }
            if(!iterator.hasNext() && l.size()<=100){
            LOG.info("Now it's less than  100,  and it also has no more 

          elements, so handing off, or they will be lost!! : => 
                             "+l.size()+" 
                                                 elements");
            handoff(l);
            l=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        }
    }

LOG.info("Done with List !!!!");
    LOG.info("Simple count is "+count);
    LOG.info("Number of elements in counter is "+at.get());
    LOG.info("Thread Name is "+Thread.currentThread());
    return NullPayload.getInstance();
```

}

```
private void handoff(List<HashMap<String, Object>> l) {
          at.getAndAdd(l.size());
          LOG.info("handoff:: Thread Name is "+Thread.currentThread());
          LOG.info("Number of elements in List is "+l.size());
          for(HashMap<String, Object> m : l){
             Object obj=m.get("CreatedBy") ;
             if(obj!=null){
                 LOG.info("OBJ====="+obj);
                 LOG.info(obj.getClass().getCanonicalName());
             }
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved: As I indicated, this was not a threading issue. It was a subtle bug in the logic that was collecting the data. When the list<100, the code branches off to the handoff method and then creates a new list. However, what happens to the element from interator.next()? It needs to be added to the new list. So the correction is in the else branch:

```
  if(l.size()<100){
        l.add((HashMap<String,Object>)payload);
    }else {

         LOG.info("Just handing off to write :: => Size is "+l.size());
         handoff(l);
         l=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
         l.add((HashMap<String,Object>)payload)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired **CopyOnWriteArrayList** (thread safe implementation of List interface may help)
Try replacing

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> l=new ArrayList<>();
```

with

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> l=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

And

```
l=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

with

```
l=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

Comment: That's what I had before and it did not work. The sames thread is used throughout. No other thread comes into play.

Comment: This statement LOG.info("Processing Next:: => "+payload); prints the correct number of times, i.e. 7348 times, so I believe that the logic related to collecting the results has a subtle bug, That's hard to pinpoint.